# AJAX receive html file

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js

I am currently writing a registration form. After the registration is successful, my server sends back an HTML file and I want AJAX to go to the login HTML.

Can someone help me plz with AJAX and JQUERY?

This is what i have:

```
      $.ajax({
                                      type: 'POST',
                                      url: "http://localhost:3000/UserRegistration",

                                      dataType: 'text',
                                      data: FormData,
                                      success: function (response)  
                                      {}
```

Also what is dataType? Is that the dataTYpe I am sending to the url or receiiving. Because I am sending a JSON file and receiving an HTML?

Do you also know how I can run a script on the new loaded page? For exampl I want to do load the login page, and append a "TickMark" image to the page: $ApprovedTick.insertAfter( 'header' ); but this wont work on the new page

Comment: You need to change your dataType to "JSON"

Comment: `dataType` = "The type of data that you're expecting back from the server." - [ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: using JSON doesnt work. Im SENDING JSON to the server and receiving an html file, so it should stay as text right?

Answer (score 1):

In ajax success event, use window.location to redirect to login page.

```
enter code here

 success: function (response)  {
      window.location = "http://localhost:3000/login.html";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you also know how I can run a script on the new loaded page?
For exampl I want to do load the login page, and append a "TickMark" image to the page:  $ApprovedTick.insertAfter( 'header' ); but this wont work on the new page

Comment: For the image part, you'll need to add script tag in `http://localhost:3000/login.html` page.

Comment: Use jquery document onready event: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 0):

Try by setting dataType to html.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "http://localhost:3000/UserRegistration",
  dataType: 'html',
  data: FormData,
  success: function (response){
     //supposing you have an html element where you want to append 
     //the response, with an id like appendResponse
     $('#appendResponse').html(response);
  }
});
```